# Imacros add a part to the URL

Tags: imacros, browser-automation

I'm trying to make a Imacro script to download multiple photos from Unsplash because I have a project and it's time consuming to download one by one.

So far, I've managed to make the following code. But it skips many images.

```js
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:https://unsplash.com/photos/*/download?force=true
```

Then I found out that the problem is Unsplash doesn't have `download?force=true` for all images.

Now, what I want is, let it add + `download?force=true` part after the URL automatically.

To clarify more, this is what I want.

```
https://unsplash.com/photos/*/ + download?force=true
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be good enough, I would think:

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:https://unsplash.com/photos/*/*
```

Only keep the parts that are always there and replace the parts that might be changing or might not be there with `*`, like you were already doing in `/photos/*/...`.

Comment: Oh, good...! Thanks for accepting my Answer... - I'm glad it works as it is the "easiest" Case/Solution, meaning the Site is already handling all Links correctly for the Download, or you would have needed to implement a different Mechanism (a bit more complicated), but that's "luckily" not needed in this Case for this Site... (Nice Site btw..., very nice and artistic Photos... on the Homepage...)